# How does Siegel's Lemma and properties of auxiliary functions helps in transcendental/irrationality proofs?

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

I know this Lemma appears more in trascendental number theory, but I saw a proof of the irrationality of $e^\pi$ it's a proof by contradiction, finding a integer between $0$ and $1$, but to that it's uses a few ideas, like the Lemma and other things, that I don't understand. I'm more interested in the irrational theory rather than the transcedental part (I'm not there yet), but it's fine to include anything if it's needed.

From wikipedia: "Siegel's lemma refers to bounds on the solutions of linear equations obtained by the construction of auxiliary functions"

In the proof that I read for $e^\pi$ the auxiliary function came from a two variable polynomial.

Also from wikipedia, these auxiliary functions must have some properties "such as being $0$ for many arguments, or having a zero of high order at some point"

Why are the properties above needed in a irrationality proof?

How finding bounds to the solutions of these auxiliary functions helps in the proof?

Comment: "In the proof that I read" discussing a proof without copying it ?

Comment: The proof It's almost 20 pages long. The person suitable to answer my question must be someone already familiar with the topic and proofs of transcedental numbers, or proofs of theorems like the gelfond theorem or this Siegels Lemma. Even on the wiki page of auxiliary functions says "They are functions that appear in most proofs in this area of mathematics (transcedental number theory)" so the person who's gonna answer this must work on the subject. The proof can be found at "Making Transcendence Transparent" by  Edward Burger.